# GLMM with nested and random effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have been trying to apply the correct model with `GLMM` to a data set that I believe has nested and random effects.

Specimens were collected from 7 sites from 4 states that fell into 3 biome and 3 latitude groupings and a different number of families (replicates) were obtained (see image). Basically state X is either in Biome A with state W or in Latitude B1 with state Y.

[Grouping scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7myr8.jpg)

Specimens were then subjected to 3 temperature treatments and most of my data is not normally distributed.
I've been toying with these two models because I first want to know if Biome or Latitude grouping has a larger affect on my outcomes:

```
a1 <- glmer(DV ~ Temp * Biome + (Biome:State) + (State:Site) + (Site:Family) + (1|Family), data = dat, family = Gamma)
AIC=11607.51
a2 < -glmer(DV ~ Temp * Latitude + (Latitude:State) + (State:Site) +(Site:Family) + (1|Family), data = dat, family = Gamma)
AIC=11645.71
```

The biome AIC is lower but I feel confused when I look at a graph of averages by grouping over temperatures like this:

[Graph of mean +/- se](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlCR3.jpg)

I've gone over a couple of nested GLMM (HGLMS modeling in R, Cake example- https://books.google.com/books?id=cTsrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=hglms+in+r+cake&source=bl&ots=8bAJ9CtUJl&sig=4RYWiaYySBGl-_ths11fyxEEwGo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2w8zjjqHZAhXE54MKHdohAnYQ6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=hglms%20in%20r%20cake&f=false) and this Tufts guide (http://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html)

Comment: I don't understand why you include `state` and `site` as fixed effects. Wouldn't a nested random effect be more appropriate?

Comment: @Roland I thought this way would allow me to understand if there are differences within the state between the two sites? Can you explain further please?